# Unable to get Rendering datasource with query like local:/Data/ Teaser 1

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client

I am trying to get all rendering datasources added to an item. I used the below code

```
var renderings = InnerItem.Visualization.GetRenderings(InnerItem.Database.Resources.Devices.GetAll().Where(d
    => d.Name.ToLower() == "default").First(), true);

 var renderingReferences = renderings?.Where(r =>!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Settings.DataSource)).ToList();
```

I see that datasources with static path are returned but  those datasources for whom the path is like
**local:/Data/ Teaser 1** are returned empty.

Is there a way to get the value of such datasources(target item id) instead of returning an empty value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If local or page relative SXA data sources are not resolved you need to resolve them manually. Run `resolveRenderingDatasource` pipeline:

```
ResolveRenderingDatasourceArgs renderingDatasourceArgs = new ResolveRenderingDatasourceArgs(YOUR_DATA_ROURCE_STRING);
renderingDatasourceArgs.CustomData.Add("contextItem", CONTEXT_ITEM);
CorePipeline.Run("resolveRenderingDatasource", renderingDatasourceArgs);

string resolvedDataSource = renderingDatasourceArgs.Datasource;
```

Comment: Thanks @David for your answer. Your code helped me in resolving the issue.

Comment: @aruntiwari How were you able to fix this? I am getting the same error but my issue with the above code is that I do not have a value for YOUR_DATA_SOURCE_STRING so that pipeline won't work. From your question it would appear that you would be having the same issue as well?